# django + nginx - auto starting django server

Tags: django, nginx

I'm using nginx+fastcgi via unix socket to my django site. I'm using the following command to start the django site:

```
python manage.py runfcgi socket=/var/run/fcgi.django.sock method=prefork daemonize=true
```

How do I make this autostart in the event of reboot or is there some better way of starting the django server?

Also, is what I'm doing best practice? I don't have much experience with python servers so my biggest concern is reliability / performance. Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried nginx and uWSGI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To autostart such a process you need to use a process manager like [supervisor](http://supervisord.org). Supervisor will then automatically start your process on system reboot and provide you a central place to manage your custom processes.

Most people prefer the [django + nginx + uwsgi](http://www.jeremybowers.com/blog/post/5/django-nginx-and-uwsgi-production-serving-millions-page-views/) or [django + nginx + gunicorn](http://senko.net/en/django-nginx-gunicorn/) stacks.